# AS 204 / Apollo 1 fire

Tags: capsule, fire, hatch, apollo-1

I have read that the three astronauts lost their lives in the CM capsule, when fire broke out on the AS 204 / Apollo 1 launch trials, as they could not open the inside opening hatch because of internal pressure. The question is if the hatch was bigger in size (presumed so) than the opening, for inside sealing purposes, how was it put inside the capsule in the first place?

Comment: The room I am just sitting in has three windows and two doors, all opening to the inside, all bigger than the frame.

Answer (score 7):

It's a trapezoidal hatch; I assume it went in diagonally.

This is a picture of the Block I hatch from Apollo 4 (the same hatch design as Apollo 1). The blue box represents the cross-section of the vertically-tallest part of the hatch, plus a small amount of clearance; the purple box has the same dimensions as the blue box. As you can see, it should fit easily through the hole.

[image]

Comment: The contrasting case to the classic "why are most manhole lids circular?"

Comment: @TomGoodfellow Cool! Now I can't stop wondering why some aren't.

Comment: @uhoh: often the same reason: you can get a longer object through a rectangular opening for the same amount of metal in the cover.  Now, work out why rectangular manhole covers are often divided into two triangular halves :-)

Comment: @Borogove.. If it was rectangular, it is possible, BUT... the pictures show it to be almost SQUARE... and as far as the question of manhole lids, I think it is easier to construct  (& seal) a circular opening.

Comment: @Russel.. If it was a rectangular hatch, what you say seems logical. But all the pictures I have seen, depict it as almost square... Thats why I asked the question. Hope this also addresses Mittag's comment.

Comment: @ Russel. I agree that the difference is about 1.4 times... Pythagoras told us so, I know. I anticipate some amount of thickness of the sealing (which, by the way will not be a few Millimeters, but much more - say 2-3 inches thick, considering their expected geometry and associated holding metalwork etc). for the purpose. That is what will also add to the "effective" entry dimension, and hence might prove to be an hinderance, specifically at the corner. The "1.4" is only at the corner points, along the edges, it starts reducing..

Comment: And of course if all else fails, you can simply make the hole bigger, put the hatch inside, then patch up the hole again. (Or, put another way: the frame doesn't need to be installed before you bring the hatch inside.)

Comment: The shape was neither a square nor a rectangle. It was an isoceles trapezoid. Not a planar trapezoid but a bend one to fit to the cone of the capsule. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid.

Comment: *"It's a trap...ezoid!"*